# Change combobox selected text

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I would like to change the text of the selected item in a combobox through a binding (if possible).

My combobox ItemSource is bound to a list of enum values.  Something like GreaterThan, LessThan, EqualsTo, etc.

When an item is selected I would like the displayed text to change to "=" or ">" or "<", etc.

I have a property that returns a string value of each enum value, I just can't figure out where to bind it.  I've tried `Text="{Binding GetStringValue"` and various other things like `SelectedValuePath="{Binding GetStringValue}"`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible approaches: 1. create a wrapper class for the enum, declare a property within that class to return text to be displayed. 2. Use custom `DataTemplate` for the `ComboBox`, and use converter to convert enum to it's display value.

Comment: Anyway, you need to give more context to have people giving more concrete suggestion/example (post the enum declaration, show how you populate the combobox, etc, so people can focus on the core problem).

Comment: I appreciate the recommendations for the possible approaches.  I'm looking into them.  I do think I found what I was looking for with the ComboBox properties SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, and DisplayMemberPath.

Comment: I did what you recommended with the wrapper class, then I just set the property returned for DisplayMemberPath to the altered string representation of my enum.

Comment: If you can give us more information, or show us code for create a possible solution to your question.